# JavaScript not gathering post information in added .php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm working on my first page for my exam and i must use the undersceleton theme.
I have created a custom .php file but the code won't work, the javascript doesn't seem to pick up the post information from WP. If i use the same code on the index.php it works just fine.
According to what information i managed to gather i must call in the added .php for the header and footer, which i did and it still doesn't work. The header with the nav bar and footer are loading perfectly but the posts won't.

I also tried to copy the content from the page.php or content.php nothing seems to work.
Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php /* Template Name: ekszerek */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Domine:400,700|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">



<div class"container">

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 grid_ss">
          <?php   /* Variable for row creation */
            $startRow = true;
            $postCounter = 0; ?>
            
          <?php /* Loop start*/ if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

          <?php if ($startRow) {
              echo '<!-- START OF INTERNAL ROW --><div class="row">';
              $startRow = false; } ?>
          <?php $postCounter += 1; ?>
          
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="paper"> 
                <div class="poster" >
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                       <a class="img_thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                     <?php the_post_thumbnail( 380, 288 ); ?>
                       </a>
                     <?php endif; ?>
             </div>
                <div class="posted_on">
                   <?php underskeleton_posted_on(); ?>
             </div>
                <h1 class="paper_h1">
                    <?php if ( is_single() ) { the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
                   } else {
              the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); 
                } if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
                </h1>
                <hr/> <!-- Text separator -->
             <div class="paper_p">
                   <?php echo get_excerpt(); ?>
             </div>
               <a class="btn" href=(<?php the_permalink(); ?>)>Megnyit</a>
           <div class="space"></div>
        <h2 class="paper_h2">
            <!-- .entry-meta -->
        </h2>
      </div>
     </div> 
       
       <?php  /*  Check if counter hits 3, if yes start new row */
          if ( 3 === $postCounter ) {
            echo '</div><!-- end of row -->';
              $startRow = true;
              $postCounter = 0; } ?>
       <?php /* End of the loop */ endwhile; ?>
            
            <?php /* If you are returning an odd number of posts (i.e., anything other than a multiple of 3), we will need to close the row div.*/
                if ($postCounter !== 0 ) { echo '</div><!-- end of row -->'; } ?>
            <?php else:  ?>
        <div class="page-header"><h1>Uh Oh!</h1></div>
              <p>Sorry, for some reason the contents of this page isn't displaying.</p>
            <?php endif; ?> 
  </div>
</div>


<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you provide more info on what's not working? Are there any errors?

Comment: Hi, the page would simply not display any of the blog posts, there are no errors, here is the link to the page: https://annamuczi.lorand-balazs.eu maybe it's easyer to explain what isn't working if i just show, if you access the page you will see the posts displayed in 3 columns. The code i posted above controls that. If you go to the last page: Ekszerek22 it should do the same, but for some reason it won't.

Comment: What Javascript? There's no JS in your code snippet at all.